# Android view animation lifecycle

Tags: java, android, view, android-animation

I want to ask, if animation would be canceled when view is destroyed for example on configuration change.

I have animation with delay and a callback. So I am worried if after view destroy callback would be executed or not.

```
 view.animate()
     .setStartDelay(2000)
     .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //do something
            }
        });
```

Comment: if you have animation with delay, and because of config changes if view is destroyed, animation wont happen because the view is newly instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `anim.cancel();`  you can also call `anim.reset();`.

refer [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#cancel%28%29)